# Matlab plots with a very low resolution when using -nodesktop option

Tags: matlab, cron, resolution

I'm having trouble with the resolution of matlab plots when the function is run via a cronjob using the `-nodesktop` option. The function plots, and saves (using the print function) a number of figures. When run from the matlab desktop, they plot and save according to the specified resolutions with no problems. But when run via a cronjob with the `-nodesktop` option, the resolutions are very poor (low).

This is essentially what I'm currently doing:

```
fh = figure;

set(fh,'Position',[0 0 1360 470]);

plot(somedata);

print(fh,'-dpng',figpath,'-painters');
```

Note that I've also tried specifying a print resolution:

```
print(fh,'-dpng',figpath,'-r300');
```

But this ends up with corrupt files. I'm not sure why. I'm using `-painters` because I read somewhere that if the plot is somewhat complicated it can default to `opengl` which ruins prints but this doesn't seem to be the issue (with or without the option, the plots are the same).

I've also tried:

```
set(fh,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
```

which does not solve the problem.

The cronjob runs the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/matlab -nodesktop -r "startup; perform_plots; exit"
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the output of `get(fh)`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue.

By running matlab as a cronjob, the DISPLAY environmental variable wasn't set. As a result there was no X display for matlab to utilise. I don't know how it still managed to plot anything at all but it did and did so with a very low resolution.

The solution is to set the appropriate display before hand. e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:1.0

/usr/local/bin/matlab -nodesktop -r "startup; perform_plots; exit"
```

In case you want to run it on a box that doesn't have an X server, you can set up a dummy X server using Xvfb (X virtual frame buffer). This also has the advantage of using a display separate to the one you may be working on so jobs can run in the background without plots randomly appearing while you work.